# Assign geolocation to var before sent to server

Tags: javascript, geolocation

Im a javascript learner and have some trouble with my script i hope someone has time to help me. 
In short I want the script to get position of user, save it to a variable and send the position of an object to the server.

I have 3 different objects in my actual script. I want to assign a position to the object before sent to server. I know this can be solved more elegant than having 3 functions (getPositionobject1, 2, 3) that all contain the same if statement. But this is a good starting point.

This script run OK, but sendToServer get called before geometry/position has been assign. Any advice of how i can arrange my code to make sure sendToServer() is called after geometry is assigned?

Here is a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/mw7cgwwz/22/

```
function getPositionobject1() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
          var timeoutVal = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            displayPosition,
            displayError,
            { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: timeoutVal, maximumAge: 0 }
          );
          sendObjectOneToServer(); //This get called before geometry is defined 
}


function displayPosition(position) {
  alert("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + ", Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude)
  geometry = (position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude).toString()
}


sendToServer() {
    var postData =
        'stuff' + geometry
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and second parameter of [Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) are callback functions, they are called when the method has finished (successfully or not).

Create an anonymous function for you success-Callback, and put it in your "displayPosition"-method, that is called with the object as an argument:

```
function getPositionobject1(objectid) {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        var timeoutVal = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            function(position) {displayPosition(position, objectid)},
            displayError,
            { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: timeoutVal, maximumAge: 0 }
        );
    }
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hc6tobgb/)

(Instead of a string, you could pass the object itself)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do that,because I have 3 different objects, I need to define what object that are going sent to the server. In my case its defined by the function name getPositionobject1() I know the code is redundant but I will have to have 3 functions one for each object. Im sure there is a better way of doing it, but im not sure how

Comment: Updated. It is messy i know. In my case as it is now. getPositionobject1() get position of the object1 and send it to the server. I hope it make more sence

Comment: The fiddle is still the same as before. Did you click "update"?

Comment: Sorry you are right, did not realize the link to the fiddle changed after each update. I updated the link now

Comment: Yes thank you! That definitely put me back on track. Kind of what I was hoping for, to reuse the code better.